# CSS ol, li, margin and padding

Tags: css, html

I have some troubles:

I am using something like this:

```html
<ol>
  <li>Titel</li>
  <ol>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
  </ol>
  <li>Titel</li>
  <ol>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
  </ol>
</ol>
```

I am now using a Padding of 70px and a margin of -30px on all titles. This works totaly fine aslong as the content is not longer than 1 row, or longer than 3 rows. As soon as there are only two rows, the number from my ol container is in a completely wrong spot.

I do not know if that is enough informations on my problem, but if you got a solution, or even better an explantation for this, that would be great.

Thanks a lot

Edit:

I am sorry but I found my mistake soon after I asked this question, the mistake was not in the html, which was not written by me, but created by a program I am using. I needed this negative margin to create an anchor on my website so the if you press that specific link, it would go to that point with a margin to the top. In the end I just created an invisible divcontainer which I moved to that point.

Sorry for that

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: A code example that *shows* the problem is far more useful than one that doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

To create valid HTML you need to nest the OL tags within your LI tags so it should look like below. See if that helps.

```
<ol>
  <li>Titel
      <ol>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
      </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Titel
      <ol>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
      </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I agree, the code in the question is not valid in html5. This one is agreed by the W3C validator.
Always try to check your syntax here to avoid issues with your html code:
https://validator.w3.org/

And try this tool to check if your .css file is valid or not : https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ And please if the answer solved your issue mark the answer as correct, or give some feedback to d3v_1 @bendajo